# ExpressJS умирает?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

Я пока изучал `ExpressJS` случайно увидел слово:

> Я пока не совсем понимаю. ExpressJS уже мёртв, а все его стремятся изучить.

Я очень хочу стать **FullStack JS Программистом**, осваиваю **MongoDB**, **React**, а также **ExpressJS**.
У меня пока что с ними **по отдельности** всё хорошо, вот только немножко с **Express**'ом есть трудности слабые, но я стремлюсь их исправить. Но после той цитаты, я не понял, мне уходить c **Express**'а, он же мёртв? Или же перейти на **Fastify**? (Он меня немного пугает, непривычно). Можете мне сказать, могу ли я ещё несколько лет программировать на **Express**'е, или он на гране?

Comment: Откуда вы черпали данную информацию? Это же бред полнейший. Он не на грани, он работает и по сей день, а вот сколько он проживет знать никто не может. Программист выбирает инструменты на основе потребностей и актуальности, вам нужно овладеть применением таких инструментов, вам необходимо быть более гибким и не привязываться к каким-либо инструментам, вы сами определяете тот стек, который вам нужен.

Comment: @MoloF это хорошо что Express ещё работает. На хабре я узнал эту информацию [именно здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/434962)

Comment: Ну так откройте комментарии под этим постом, вам все станет яснее некуда. И пожалуйста, сначала создайте приложение, а только потом оптимизируйте его, не тратьте время на то, что вам может вообще не пригодится. Обозначьте свою задачу, выберите стек, сравните стек с другими инструментами, выберите на основе ваших знаний и потребностей тот инструмент, который считаете нужным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express еще долго не умрет, потому что на нем было написано не мало проектов которые нужно поддерживать.

Comment: Одно из другого никак не вытекает